User is not authenticated even though Login was successful
I have 2 web apps:

Web_App_A : handles authentication
Web_App_B : the actual application

After the user successfully logs in in A (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true), I create a JWT access token which is passed to B.
B receives the JWT and can read it, so:
var UserFullName = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst("UserFullName")?.Value; 

shows the correct value.
The problem is when I check the authentication status in B,
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false.

Both have Program.cs, where this part is the same:
// JWT Configuration
var jwtKey = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]; // Read from appsettings
var jwtValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"]; // Read from appsettings
var jwtValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"];  // Read from appsettings

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = jwtValidIssuer,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = jwtValidAudience,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtKey)),
    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role // Parse roles correctly from token
};
});


Did you add the [Authorize] attribute on your controller method?

How do you pass the token to B? For example, add it to the Authorization field in the HTTP request header? You can check whether there is configuration
app.UseAuthentication()
app.UseAuthorization()
and the expiration time of the token.
You can also check whether the configuration items in TokenValidationParameters are consistent with the configuration used when generating JWT.

After adding Bearer as the authentication type for the identity, it all works.
// Add "Bearer" as the authentication type for the identity
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(_jwtToken.Claims, "Bearer");

